# How to set a primitive array field using reflection?

Tags: java, parsing, reflection

I am trying to write a function which takes an object as an argument and auto-fills it from some binary, using reflection on its class.

I've written some code that looks something like this (simplified):

```
for (Field f: obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
{
    try 
    {
        if (f.getType().isPrimitive())
        {
            Object value = getPrimitiveValue(f.getType());
            f.set(obj, value);
        }
        else if (f.getType().isArray())
        {
            Class<?> compType = f.getType().getComponentType();
            Vector<Object> container = new Vector<Object>();    

            for (int i = 0; i < SOME_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                Object item = getPrimitiveValue(compType);
                container.add(item);
            }

            Object[] arr = container.toArray();
            f.set(obj, arr); 
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

while `getPrimitiveType` reads from a static byte buffer a primitive type according to the component type.

the vector container is set with the correct values. If the component type is short, for instance, it becomes a `short[]` array.

However, the call `f.set(obj, arr)` which tries to set the value of the array field `f` to `arr` throws the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set [B field MyClass.myArrayField to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is using reflection your only option? Reflections are not a quick or robust way of doing things

Comment: Well, of course not, but I have many structures (hundreds) which I would like to read from a binary into an object and since I'm only interested in viewing the data and don't care about performance this seems like the way to do it

Comment: Your code seem to have some problems... e.g. how is that the container.toArray() line compiles if container variable is defined within the preceding else-if? Perhaps some problem copying the code?

Comment: Also object[] won't ever compile....

Comment: @ValentinRuano yeah I copied the code and cut unnecessary stuff... I'll edit it, thanks :)

Comment: Also you don't define getPrimitiveValue but getPrimitiveType which is never used in the code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is Vector.toArray() returns an array of type Object [], even though it may contain objects of the correct type - this is not the same thing, hence the IllegalArgumentException.

Also you can never cast between Object [] and arrays of primitive types. Instead you can use the utility functions in java.lang.reflect.Array, e.g. newInstance(), set(array, index, value) etc.

```
public class Test {

    private static short[] horses;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("horses");

        Object array = Array.newInstance(field.getType().getComponentType(), 3);
        Array.set(array, 0, (short)123);
        Array.set(array, 1, (short)456);
        Array.set(array, 2, (short)789);

        field.set(new Test(), array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that field.set would work here, e.g. dummyTypedArray won't ever be a short[] (perhaps a Short[]) as short[] does not extend Object[]. The (Object[]) will probably fail.

Comment: To be more concrete, it will work in your example but it does not address the question.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? let me know if you need any more information